# return object property using lodash from array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have been trying to return a property of an object by filtering it first. Here's what I did:

```
var characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'blocked': false },
  { 'name': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'blocked': true },
  { 'name': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'blocked': false }
];

_.find(characters, function(chr) {
     return  chr.age == 40
});
```

It returns whole object where as I want to return specific property. Can anyone guide me how can I do it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just access the property `age` after you filtered the object you need.

Comment: i can do that but i wanted to be done in method .

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could use the Lodash [chaining ability](https://lodash.com/docs#lodash). As its name implies, it enables you to chain Lodash methods calls. [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) and [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) are appropriate here:

```js
const characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'blocked': false },
  { 'name': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'blocked': true  },
  { 'name': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'blocked': false },
]

const names = _(characters)
  .filter(c => c.age < 40)
  .map('name')
  .value()

alert(names)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.3.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

For the record, this is how you can do in pure JS:

```js
const characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'blocked': false },
  { 'name': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'blocked': true  },
  { 'name': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'blocked': false },
]

const names = characters
  .filter(c => c.age < 40)
  .map(c => c.name)

alert(names)
```

Comment: it works, i have used find over filter is because filter loop through all values and then return matched array. thanks for helping me out

Comment: `pluck` isn't in lodash anymore :(

Comment: I updated the answer to match this API update, actually `pluck` is simply a `map`. This is actually even clearer with the ES6 arrow functions.

Comment: `_.map` also supports the `_.property` iteratee shorthand like `_.map(characters, 'name')`

Answer (score 7):

[_.property](https://lodash.com/docs#property)

```
var array = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]
array.map(_.property('a')) // => [1, 3]
```

[_.map](https://lodash.com/docs#property) short hand

```
var array = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]
_.map(array, 'a') // => [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
_.result(_.find(characters, function(obj) {
       return obj.age === 40;
}), 'name');
```

Answer (score 0):

As *elclanrs* mentioned in comment before obvious solution is just to access the property `age` after you filtered the object.

But if you wanted to be done in method, you can first extract all age values and then allpy `find` function on them:

```js
var ageValues = _.pluck(characters, 'age'); //returns [36, 40, 1]

var resultAgeValue = _.find(ageValues, function(ageValue) {
   return  ageValue < 40
});
```

or, better looks in chain:

```js
var resultAgeValue = _(characters).pluck('age').find(function(ageValue) {
   return  ageValue < 40
});
```

try jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqr/j8rL780u/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work, it only returns the first matching character.

Comment: Actually my jsfiddle returns the first matching character by desing! The original code in the question also returns only first matching object - author was using `find`, not `filter`!

Comment: The author appears to begin with Lodash. It doesn't make much sense to return only one value when considering a non-sorted array. Hence my use of `filter`.